# Routing in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, web, routes, sinatra

I have an application where the user fills out a form at **/search** and I want that to output to **/search/results**.

In my app.rb, I've attempted to call

```
post '/search' do
    ...       
    erb :search/results
end
```

However that fails.  My directory structure is:

```
views
-search
--results
```

But it fails.  Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works 100% (i use it):

```
post '/search' do
  ...       
  erb :"search/results"
end
```

[`Thats method`](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L838) do magic with render engine in Sinatra like `erb` or `slim` be careful `:"some\thing` and `"some\thing"` different things!

Comment: Wait, how do you get it to load the resources?  In the nested routes, it doesn't load any javascript or css assets.  What's the Sinatra way of handling this?

Comment: Ah, I see, I need to make them absolute references.